# Null exception in browser activity during url open

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have an activity with only browser view. Every time application tries to open url I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

that refers to this line:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

After commenting this line, activity opens normal from the other view. Here is the code that tries to load web page:

```
 public class Browser extends AppCompatActivity {


 WebView mWebView;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(layout.activity_browser);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);


       mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{karolklimek.mpkdisplay2/karolklimek.mpkdisplay2.Browser}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at karolklimek.mpkdisplay2.Browser.onCreate(Browser.java:38)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

And the content of content_browser XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="karolklimek.mpkdisplay2.Browser"
    >
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did it occur to you that `mWebView` might be null and that you should check your id, import and layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in `setContentView()`. You have to pass the integer value of your layout from `R.java` file. Thus you have to pass `R.layout.activity_browser` instead of `layout.activity_browser`.

It should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
```

**UPDATE**

In your code, you are setting the content view to be `activity_browser` but from your question, I understand that you have the webview in `content_browser.xml` file, and thus you are getting an NPE.

Simplest way to solve the error would be to move the webview to your `activity_browser.xml` or change your setContentView to load `content_browser` instead of `activity_browser`.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a lot of time that the problem was in pausing another activity, but it was so simple.

Comment: Hahaha...glad that it helped you.. :) Happy coding.. !!

Answer (score 0):

From the code we can see that the layout is not loaded, due to that the mWebView object not initialized and you are end up with the NPE.

The code should be 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
instead
setContentView(layout.activity_browser);